# OnTriggerEnter with user input in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, collision-detection

I'm trying to create a simple melee attack in Unity but am having trouble with the code. I have the following written:

```
public class meleeAttack : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            print("What's up!!!");
    }


}
```

That works fine by itself, however, I want to make it so the message only pops up when the player presses a key. I tried adding the following to the OnTriggerEnter method:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
            print("What's up!!!");
    }
```

The issue is that now the message will no longer show up, even if I'm pressing the F key. Is there a way I can incorporate this code in order to call the message only when the player presses the F key and is in contact with the gameObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do the GetKeyUp in the update loop and set a boolean flag that is then checked for in the OnTriggerEnter.

Or vise-versa depending on your timing requirements (ie. set the boolean flag in OnTriggerEnter, and check for it within the Update loop).  [I'd likely do it this way given your description]

The problem you have is OnTriggerEnter will only fire once, and so it won't keep polling the keyboard for changes in the key state, which is why you need a check in the Update loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OnTrigggerStay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) instead of onTriggerEnter and you can avoid speical bool in Update event.

> OnTriggerStay is called almost all the frames for every Collider other
>   that is touching the trigger

something like this, you required

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
            print("What's up!!!");
    }
```